# Use of was/were vs ing verb

Tags: word-usage

He pulled his hair back from his face, his fingers tugging so hard on the blond strands that they stretched the skin taut on his forehead.

Can anyone explain me why "was" is not used before tugging, or tugged simply?

Comment: "Was" is not needed: _his fingers tugging so hard on the blond strands that they stretched the skin taut on his forehead_ is called an 'absolute' construction. Absolutes are non-finite clauses with a subject and a non-finite verb that are set apart from the rest of the sentence by a comma or other punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

First, *fingers* is plural, so you'd have to say his fingers *were* tugging at his hair, rather than "his fingers was(*) tugging...".

Second, using the progressive tense here emphasizes that the tugging by the fingers is providing a further description of how he pulled his hair, rather than as a separate action.

Comment: The verb "be" is not missing: _his fingers tugging so hard on the blond strands that they stretched the skin taut on his forehead_ is called an 'absolute' construction. Absolutes are non-finite clauses with a subject and a non-finite verb that are set apart from the rest of the sentence by a comma or other punctuation. Progressive is not a tense, but an aspect. The non-finite clause here has progressive aspectuality, as distinct from the progressive aspect where "be" is required.